# Override Orchard Blog Template

Tags: orchardcms

I'm building a custom theme.  I need to override how the list of blog posts is rendered to match my desired look.  I can't seem to figure out how to render the blog post's title( or any other piece of info for that matter ).  All of my markup and hard coded info renders, but the dynamic data does not.

Inside of my theme folder "~/Views/Items/Content-BlogPost.cshtml":

```
<div class="media row-fluid">
    <div class="span1 hidden-phone">
        <!-- Date desktop -->
        <div class="date-wrapper"><span class="date-m">Jan</span> <span class="date-d">20</span> </div>
        <!-- Meta details desktop -->
        <p class="meta muted"><i class="icon-user"></i><a href="#">Alex</a> </p>
    </div>
    <!-- PROBLEM IS HERE!!!!!!!!!!! Title does not render! -->
    <div class="span11"><h1>@Display(Model.Content.Title)</h1>
        <div class="media-body">
            <div class="tags"><a href="#" class="tag">coding</a> / <a href="#" class="type">event</a></div>
            <h4 class="title media-heading"><a href="blog-post.htm">a nec in sed hac ultrices cursus</a></h4>

            <!-- Meta details mobile -->
            <ul class="inline meta muted visible-phone">
                <li><i class="icon-calendar"></i><span class="visible-desktop">Created:</span> Sun 20th Jan 2013</li>
                <li><i class="icon-user"></i><a href="#">Alex</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="blog-post.htm" class="media-object">
                <img src="img/blog/ape.jpg" alt="Picture of frog by Ben Fredericson">
            </a>
            <p>@Display(Model.Content)</p>
            <ul class="inline links">
                <li><a href="blog-post.htm" class="btn btn-mini"><i class="icon-circle-arrow-right"></i>Read more</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog-post.htm#comments" class="btn btn-mini"><i class="icon-comment"></i>50 Comments</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's because Model.Content.Title doesn't exist. You need to go through the TitlePart.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Bertrand, I tracked down the way to do this.

Model.ContentItem.TitlePart.Title